# Call variable into a sqlite row

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a python script that reads a conf file and prints out matches. 
These matches are all stored in a varialbe. 
I want to be able to insert the values into a sqlite table.. 

File reads: 
Hello Asia 
World Mumbai 
Hello America 
World Chicargo 
Hello Australia 
World Sydney

## Here is my scipt.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import sqlite3
File = open("/home/abc/def.conf", "r")
for line in File:
        if re.match("(hello)", line, re.IGNORECASE):
                  Continent = line.lstrip("hello")
                  print Continent
        if re.match("(world)", line, re.IGNORECASE):
                  City = line.lstrip("world")
                  print a
#Creating SQL TABLE
sqlite_file = '/home/abc/dbase.sqlite3'
table_name1 = 'table1'
new_column1 = 'Continent'
new_column2 = 'City'

conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE {tn} ({nf})'\
        .format(tn=table_name1, nf=new_column1))
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE {tn} ADD COLUMN '{cn}'"\
        .format(tn=table_name1, cn=new_column2))
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table1
(`Continent`,`City`) VALUES ($Continent, $City)");
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

-------------- VALUES ($Continent, $City)") ??? THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to insert values from Python variables is as follows:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table1 (`Continent`,`City`) VALUES (?,?)",(Continent,City));
```

`?` represents a parameter and the second argument of the `execute` function is an iterable (tuple, list) of your corresponding variables.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I get only the first row.. How do i print all matches on each row?

Comment: Are you calling this from inside the loop?